# Where to find CallSid or From when using twiliojs Twilio.Device.connect to dequeue a call?

Tags: twilio

In my js I am just using:

```
Twilio.Device.connect({QueueFriendlyName: 'generic'});
```

The TwiML generated in the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Queue>
            generic
        <Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I succesfully dequeue a call and connect with the caller.

But in the connect callback handler:

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
    console.log(conn);
    console.log(conn.parameters);
});
```

I can't find anywhere `CallSid`, `From`, or any familiar call data, conn.parameters is empty.

Is it normal? Is there anyway to retrieve these information?

Also, is it possible to pass back to the softphone client any data collected with Gather in the TwiML?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this specifically answers your question, but I ended up here looking for a similar answer (why my parameters weren't being populated), and thought I'd share with the rest of the internet:

On *outbound* calls, twilio does not populate the connection parameters, that is just for incoming calls.

To get parameters populated on outbound calls, upgrade to at least twilio.js 1.2 -- 1.1 (which is what I was using) does not support parameters for outgoing calls.

(Thanks to skim